# How to update user email in git repo cloned from SVN

Tags: git, github, git-svn

I cloned my SVN repo to GIT. When I did it I pointed file with user names.

```
user1 = User1 <user1@mail.com>
user2 = User2 <user2@mail.com>
```

Then I updated to github. All users are recognised except one. I discovered that I made speling mistake in email.

I used this method `git --filter-branch`.

[Change the author and committer name and e-mail of multiple commits in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/how-do-i-change-the-author-of-a-commit-in-git)

And it changed this user mail successfully. But now when i push to github it sais it is up-to-date and do not want to update user email on github.

How do I update it?

Comment: Is your github repo public and can you post a link?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it from another side:

GitHub user may have more than one e-mail, all e-mails will be linked to correct user in commits (AFAICS)

Comment: That is true but email it turned to be assigned is not accessible. I men there is even whitespace. There was list of users and I missed it somehow one user was `user - User <mail email@mail.com>`